# How to find the app that causes crashes?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, crashes, logging

Where should I begin the hunt for the cause of crashes / reboots when logging apps do not work anymore?

Comment: Do you mean logcat?

Comment: yes, for example...

Comment: Maybe you should find out why it doesn't work! ^^

Comment: This I have already found out. For privacy reasons, applications may no longer read each others log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDDgoxvQsrQ&feature=youtu.be&t=1369s) from the Google I/O conference, in Jelly Bean applications can no longer read the system log for other applications, they can only read their own log. This has broken most (all?) system log readers, [here's a blog post](http://nolanlawson.com/2012/09/02/catlog-jives-with-jelly-bean-goes-open-source/) from a developer of such an application talking about how it has affected his application.

The only way to have an app read other apps system log entries when using Jelly Bean is to root the phone.

Although other apps can't read the log files it is *apparently* possible to do it from the PC, try giving [LogShark](https://gist.github.com/hrj/5983971) a go.

Comment: Root is not necessary. I have created a utility to collect logs: https://gist.github.com/hrj/5983971

Comment: @HRJ That looks good, I'll add it into my answer. I do say "only way to have *other apps*" so the answer isn't incorrect but again, good work.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest most simple way that will give you definitive results is to remove all apps
and install them one at a time until you install one that starts your problem.

If you just installed an app recently and think it may be questionable, uninstall it and see if your problem is gone. This in all honesty is a lengthy process.

Comment: The question asks about logging apps in general suggesting it's not one application causing the OP a problem.